# "Application failed codesign verification" . . . but was accepted by the app store?

Tags: ios, code-signing

Can anyone explain this one.  I just built my app for distribution.  I got the warning below.  But when I submitted anyway . . . it all worked just fine.  Status is now "waiting for review."

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains
disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=[long path]
AssertMacros: message,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 554
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: [long path]/embedded.mobilepro- (null)
```

Comment: What the?  How do you know it went through?  Is it in ITC?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to me, it had to do with the path of one of my resource files being too long after it was put into the derived data build area. You will probably be OK, but if the warning really bothers you like it did me, I got around the issue by shortening the path in my derived data settings.

http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2012/03/19/application-failed-codesign-verification/